# sonar Setting up in Azure cloud and automate through VSTS

Tags: azure, sonarqube

I just gone through some documents regarding the sonar and azure cloud ,I am new to Sonar and Azure Cloud.As per the documentation which I gone through,I got some idea on this.I have installed sonar plugin in VSTS and tried to connect to azure but As per my understanding we need to set proxy in azure servers so that I can connect to azure.But still I am not having the approach to connect sonar with Azure.Do we need to setup any private agent in VSTS and install sonar or any subscription we need to add in Azure ( End point).Please share your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Microsoft SQL Server VM in azure, then configure/install sonarqube and map 80 port (Public port) to Sonarqube port (default is 9000).
A related article: [How to setup a SonarQube server in Azure](http://donovanbrown.com/post/how-to-setup-a-sonarqube-server-in-azure).

On the other hand, the public IP address may be changed, you can use a static public IP address, more information you can refer to: [Create a VM with a static public IP address using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-deploy-static-pip-arm-portal?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Fwindows%2Ftoc.json).

Regarding the sonarqube server just can be accessible from intranet, you need to setup a private build agent (can access that sonarqube from this build agent machine), then queue build with this private build agent.

Comment: @MSFT, I will check and let you know..Thanks for the support.

Comment: For creating the private agent ,will it be cost in VSTS?

Comment: @PRAVEEN No, it's free.

Comment: Can you please help me on how to start the sonar configuration with VSTS and Azure ?Please help me out screen shots if possible.Entire my organisation is looking on this setup for all of my projects.Please help me with how to start setting up this implementation.

Comment: Do you refer to the article that I provided?

Comment: Since every document in google provides the configuration for .net project and in TFS and Visual studio,I didn't get any solution for VSTS with Azure for setting up Sonar cube for my project.So please help me out.

Comment: I referred the article.in that article they were saying to  disable internet security enhanced configuration.This disabling step where can I do? to Which server I should do this disabling ? In the first step we can create the sql server after that saying to connect server .how to connect ?

Comment: @ starian chen-MSFT,I just checked the article again,Its looks like we need an infrastructure as a service but our project is using platform as a service that means we can't have complete control over VM right ? Since the article looks like we need an SQL Server and some settings in the server we have to do.But having said that,how can I access the VM to do the changes whatever shown in that article.Please explain me.

Comment: Can you log on the azure VM through remote desktop connection?

Comment: No I can't login through remote. Instead I can login through subscription method.

Comment: What do you mean subscription method? Can you install a software with that way?

Comment: @ starian chen-MSFT, I just checked with my azure admin team to create a SQL server VM in Azure for that they replied that VM creation  will be cost and asked me to tell the cost and for the private agent in VSTS ,how much charge that they are going to charge for build minutes when we run the sonar in private agent.Can you please help me out on the cost for the dedicated VM so that I will provide the business justification to the admin team and get an approval to create a VM.

Comment: If there is any other way for the sonar setup with the existing PAAS in azure,please help me out.or else please provide the cost cuttings for the VM and build minutes.

Comment: please help me here. How much cost will be required for this vm and for build minutes.

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with azure, you can open a new thread with related azure tags.

Comment: @ starian chen-MSFT, As you said,our azure is PAAS( Platform as a  service) but as per your approach we need IAAS(Infrastructure as a service) which we can control the VM by logging with user name and password.But my company officials not agree to have the VM as a IAAS.So please help me out how can I achieve the sonar intergration in VSTS?

Comment: It is not related to VSTS, just how to setup sonarqube in azure, I am not familiar with azure, so you can open a new thread for the issue of how to setup sonarqube in azure. After that, you just add sonarqube endpoint in VSTS.

Comment: Can you please explain the steps using Private agent how we can setup Sonar in VSTS ?My organization is not ready to have a azure as LAAS.So asked me to explore using Private agent.So please guide me the steps how can I proceed?

Comment: With Private agent, you just need to setup the Sonarqube in local server, make sure it can be accessed from your private agent, after that, you need to create the Sonarqube endppoint and add Sonarqube tasks to build definition. https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Extension+for+VSTS-TFS

Comment: @ starian chen-MSFT,Thanks for your detailed steps.I could able to download the private agent and tried to configure the agent with my laptop/local machine.At particular step its failing with the below error:  Loading RSA key parameters from file C:\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.127.0\.credentials_rsaparams
[2018-02-02 11:31:54Z WARN VisualStudioServices] Attempt 1 of POST request to https://projname.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/oauth2/token failed (WinHttp Error: ERROR_WINHTTP_TIMEOUT). The operation will be retried in 10.89 seconds.

Comment: Its failing After the steps like server URL,PAT,agent pool name.Its saying connecting to server and then at testing agent connection step its taking some time and then cmd abruptly closing itself.So please do the needful.I have all the logs its creating under C:\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.127.0\_diag folder..

Comment: @ starian chen-MSFT, Can you please look at my issue and help me out?

Comment: ,Now,I successfully installed the private agent but how to run sonar through VSTS .I have installed sonar setup 5.6 version in my local laptop and the private agent is configured with my laptop. now I can see when I try to trigger the build ,I can see the private agent under the agent selection.So please let me know after this step how to proceed?

Comment: @ starian chen-MSFT , When I try to trigger the build in VSTS by selecting private agent,I can see the error like, No registered agents found in the selected queue with the following capabilities: cmd,maven. Use a different queue. Please help me out on this issue.

Comment: I think there is the task related to maven, so it needs maven capability, you need to install maven on you agent machine.

Comment: @ starian chen-MSFT,Yes I am running the maven task in the build so its expecting maven and I have installed maven from apache site.But still its expecting maven if I try to trigger build.Do I need to configure any thing after installing the maven in that private agent.If yes,please let me know what is the next step?

Comment: After install the maven, you need to restart your agent or agent machine.

Comment: @ starian chen-MSFT, I have restarted my private agent (With Laptop configured) and I can see the path M2_HOME and Path for maven under the agent capabilities section reflected but still if I trigger build its asking for mvn capability.Please help here.Any other changes I should do here in the build definition or any where?

Comment: Feel free to open a new thread with details of build definition (e.g. tasks) and error message.

Comment: @ starian chen-MSFT,I have opened the new thread on this issue.In the meanwhile can you please help me how to run sonar now though Private agent in VSTS .I have installed sonar in private agent and I can able to browse localhost:9000.Please tell me how to setup/configure sonar now.

Comment: Since you can access it by browsing localhost:9000, you have already setup/configure the sonar. What do you want to configure?

Comment: @ starian chen-MSFT,I can browse but I don't see any data in that localhost:9000 server.I want my project results in that host and can check my results.So how to run sonar in VSTS now.What configuration is required from the VSTS build definition and any command is required to run sonar  in VSTS build task .If yes where can I run ? Do I need to add any goals in VSTS tasks for that project?

Comment: @ starian chen-MSFT,Now,I found the option in VSTS build in maven task .The option is Run sonarcube analysis but if I trigger the build getting the error like ::::Downloading from central: repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/… Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:3.0..Please help here.

Comment: Do you refer to this article: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Extension+for+VSTS-TFS#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeExtensionforVSTS-TFS-AnalysingaJavaprojectwithMavenorGradle? What're tasks of your build definition?

Comment: @ starian chen-MSFT,what is meant by Publish analysis result task for sonar in VSTS ? Currently it is failing at this particular task at publish anaysis result.Please help me out.[error][SQ] API GET '/api/ce/task' failed, status code was: 401
2018-02-19T06:47:55.8632574Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;][SQ] API GET '/api/ce/task' failed, status code was: 401
2018-02-19T06:47:55.8632574Z ##[debug][SQ] Publish task error: [SQ] 
2018-02-19T06:47:55.8632574Z ##[debug]task result: Failed
2018-02-19T06:47:55.8642574Z ##[error][SQ] Could not fetch task for ID 'AWGs0JzCX3ZRkGjsM